# "They roam the galaxy looking for something, they know not what. "

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q

In the third season TNG episode "Deja Q", Q has his powers stripped by the Q Continuum and is exiled to the Enterprise in human form.   Q has a discussion with Data about humans and comes out with this line:

> **Q**: Humans are such commonplace little creatures. They roam the galaxy looking for something, they know not what.

Now, this "know not what" business is quite an archaism.   Usually in modern English we don't follow verbs with *not* except modals (can, would, do) and negatives are usually formed with such constructions (Cannot/can't, would not/wouldn't, do not/don't, did not/didn't etc.)   Colloquially, you would probably say "Humans roam the galaxy looking for something and they don't even know what they're looking for."

Is this a reference to something or just some weird affectation the writers imposed on Q here?    Why?   Has Q spoken like this at other times?

Comment: It might be a reference to classical literature, and also for dialog to be effective it has to have a rhythm and musicality to it, so this might have been the most musical construction the screenwriter was able to formulate. "They know not" is a construction used multiple times in the King James Bible.

Comment: Too, Q was always ostentatious. He may have simply been attempting to impress Picard and crew.

Comment: @Xantec:   This was dialog between Q and Data only.

Comment: @ThePopMachine https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708758/quotes Most of the quotes in there strike me as something only Q would say (compared to other characters).

Comment: @ToddWilcox — Since this episode is effectively Q's crucifixion due to his association with humans, a reference to [Luke 23:34](http://biblehub.com/luke/23-34.htm) (about humans causing more damage than we comprehend) seems appropriate.

Comment: This could be a biblical reference as mentioned by Todd, Luke 23:34: "Father, forgive them, for they know not what they do." To me it would match the condescending paternalistic attitude of Q, as well as offer the connotation that humanity needs to be forgiven for being basically apes in spaceships.

Comment: "Know not what" is a reasonably common archaic phrase, in my experience. It's almost reached the status of idiom (which often have their roots in things which once were regular parts of the language and aren't anymore, when people keep saying them anyway). Except that "know not what" isn't part of the everyday language, it's generally only used when you want to sound a bit "poetical" or "deep" (which is exactly what both Q in-universe *and* the show creators out-of-universe are doing here).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Q knows every human language far better than humans do, even Reginald Barclay in "Nth Degree." How dare you question Q's usage of the language!

Comment: I wouldn't call this an 'archaism'. It might be old fashioned, but it's still in use.

Comment: `...and they don't even know what they're looking for.`  This is the sort of English up with which I will not put!

Comment: @Pharap:   Definition from Google:  - a thing that is very old or old-fashioned.
- an archaic word or style of language or art. - the use or conscious imitation of very old or old-fashioned styles or features in language or art.

Comment: MCU Loki does this too. It's just style innit. Presumably supposed to give off the idea that the speaker is really old!

Comment: @ThePopMachine those are indeed the definitions, but words have different meanings depending on *context*. In most dictionaries, "archaic" is only used for definitions that are no longer in use *at all*. Old fashioned words will be marked as "old-fashioned" or something like that. "Archaic" has a very specific meaning when talking about language, and it's not what you think. Using "know not" is *definitely* not archaic.

Comment: @ell:   This is your opinion, but the definition right there is "the use of old-fashioned features in language".    I'm responding to the comment which is saying "it's not an archaism; it's just old-fashioned" when old-fashioned is literally the definition.

Comment: @JeffLambert Or John 4:22, hinting that, like the Samaritan woman, the Enterprise believe there's "something" out there, but not really understanding what it is, while the Q (like the Jews) have a deeper understanding of reality.

Comment: "But answer came there none —"  The Walrus and the Carpenter, by Lewis Carroll.

Comment: @ThePopMachine For what I'm calling "old fashioned", the term most dictionaries would use is 'dated'. Also I find many dictionaries are slightly off when classifying words that are or aren't still in common use. For example the Oxford dictionary classes 'bunkum' as dated, but it's still in use (although it's more common in certain regional dialects than others).

Comment: @MrLister - I'll leave it to Pop. I think it's better and clearer

Comment: @Valorum, If any change were needed, it would be "Why did Q say this like this"?  But the question title is a hook, not the complete question.   That's what the question text is for.   I don't believe any additional words are needed.

Comment: The current question title isn't actually a question though.

Comment: @Valorum:   Sometimes the title is not a question.   Sometimes it's a topic.

Comment: How old is Q? About when did he learn English?

Comment: @ThePopMachine It is not my opinion. Look at how any dictionary uses "archaic" and you'll find that I'm simply stating facts.

Comment: @ell:   I have little interest in debating the meaning of "archaic".   I do find it ironic to argue about "how any dictionary uses" the word, when I literally showed you a dictionary definition.   (Yes, I know you're going to point out that there's a difference between the dictionary definition of a word and some notion of "how they actually use it").    At any rate, I do not accept the descriptor "old-fashioned" which it seems to me usually means something like 50 years old when this construction clearly would have been equally old-fashioned even many decades ago.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Upon @Xantec's suggestion I looked for the original script.   On [st-minutiae](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/161.txt), we have a script labelled FINAL DRAFT dated 11/14/89 which actually contains this line instead!

> **Q**:  Humans are such commonplace creatures.  They roam the galaxy looking for something, **and they don't even know what it is**.
>   <sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

So this at least suggests that decisions were made by some combination of the actor and the director around shooting time to streamline the delivery.

Commentary:   The actual delivery is not only less of a mouthful, but it does sort of disambiguate the potential interpretation of the script line as "They roam the galaxy looking for something and when they do find it they don't even know what they've found" as opposed to "They roam the galaxy and they don't even know what they seek."   It's clear the intent is the second, which the actual delivery does clear up.

Comment: Good find. I was just about to post this :-)

Comment: That's what going to Juilliard will do - much better delivery than what was written

Comment: @Valorum:   Ha!  It looks like I beat you by seconds.  Chalk up one for the good guys.

Comment: @NKCampbell:   The way that is pronounced (even according to Wikipedia) is so far from how it should be pronounced that I never would have imagined it's spelt like that.

Comment: The change also avoids the interpretation that humans don't know what the galaxy is.

Comment: Dialog "fixes" like this are done often by actors and directors when otherwise good stories have clunky dialog. According to Harrison Ford, bad dialog plagued the first *Star Wars* movie, and they had to do a lot of on-the-spot fixes.

Comment: Not sure it's just for "streamlining". It also sounds more poetic.

Comment: @Barmar:   You're correct, of course, but I didn't have an evidence-based comment to make.   Machavity is addressing this.

Comment: And don't forget how, in "Q Who," when Riker tried to threaten Q, DeLancie ignored the clichéd line in the script and said, "Oh *please.*"

Comment: @Davislor - I love it, where can I find more information on that one?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "SkepticalMI" has a well-written comment on it [following the review here](https://www.jammersreviews.com/st-tng/s2/qwho.php). I’d link directly to it if I could. The script at sf-minutiae still has Riker blame Q for the loss of 18 of the crew, but Q was originally written as responding, “Stop—or you will surely die.” I couldn’t tell you whose idea it was to change the line to “Oh *please,*” but it changes Q from a manchild to a trickster-god. I’m *guessing* that the director and actor had a discussion and agreed to change it at the last minute.

Comment: @Davislor - Thanks. I meant more information on the change to the line. I wonder if it's even available (if DeLancie or the director or the writers or one of the other actors remembers making the change). No question it was a very, very good change. The original line was hack. The revised line is character.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I’m afraid I don’t know. Many of the people working behind the scenes have been sharing their recollections for decades, and possibly DeLancie or someone else have talked about it?

Comment: @ToddWilcox It's worth including the full quote from Ford: "George, you can type this shit, but you sure can’t say it."  Some people may think that George Lucas never learnt from this; I couldn't possibly comment. ;-)

Answer (score 17):

The John DeLancie Q was a loquacious character who was always turning phrases and being melodramatic. One of my favorites was this one, where Q has regained his powers, thanks to the exploits of the Enterprise

> Au contraire, mon capitaine!

Q would continue to refer to Picard as "Mon capitaine" for the rest of the series.

Comment: Q was calling Picard that nickname as far back in his first season, although the line is not in the original script for “Hide and Q.” There was a lot of conflict between Maurice Hurley and Gene Roddenberry about how to write Q, which led to Hurley demanding to be credited for the screenplay under a pseudonym because Roddenberry had rewritten it so much. The mystery and grandiosity of Q was more Roddenberry—“Mon capitan” doesn’t appear in Hurley’s draft.

Comment: Hurley’s script for “Hide and Q” was clearly intended to write the character out of the show for good. Indeed, even the episode as aired ends with Q promising never to interfere with humanity again. It was Hurley himself who would write Q’s next appearance, “Q Who,” and retcon that promise away without explanation. That’s where the character of Q finally crystallizes into how the show will use him: a sinister god, intrigued by Picard, and willing to upend the universe to force him to admit that he’s too smug.

Comment: The best part of Q's character was always his attempts to get attention and play tricks on Picard, and how Picard, while always rebuking him, clearly secretly loves the guy... Kind of like the Dean/Crowley dynamic on Supernatural...